# VBA: Convert seconds into an output of hours, minute, seconds

Tags: excel, vba

I need a code where it creates an output message box where it shows a conversion of the inputted time in seconds. This is for VBA in Excel. Thank you.

```
time = InputBox("Give me your time in seconds: ")
```

For example the output box to be if it is given 7453 seconds:

```
Your time is:
2 hours
4 minutes
13 seconds
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time is just a fraction of a day.

```
Sub kjkjk()
    Dim inpt As Double
    inpt = Application.InputBox("Give me your time in seconds: ", Type:=1)

    Dim time As Double
    time = inpt / (CDbl(24) * 60 * 60)

    MsgBox "Your time is:" & Chr(10) & Hour(time) & " hours" & Chr(10) & Minute(time) & " minutes" & Chr(10) & Second(time) & " seconds"
End Sub
```

---

One could also use:

```
time = TimeSerial(0, 0, inpt)
```

in place of

```
time = inpt / (CDbl(24) * 60 * 60)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Harry if this worked for you please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: just did! thanks again. Btw I asked another question earlier also vba, but didn't really help the one answer I got. Could you take a look at it? If you don't mind.